# Is it possible to catch mouse events in wxFrame

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, wxwidgets

I have been searching the web and trying to find out if it is possible to catch mouse events in the actual wxFrame element in wxWidgets. Various sources say it is not possible and wxPanels should be used to capture events,is that true?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mouse events are **not** propagated upwards the window hierarchy, so if your frame is entirely covered by other windows, then it doesn't get any mouse events in the first place and hence you can't catch them there.

Of course, you can always handle any event from any other window in a method of `wxFrame` class using `Bind()`. For example:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(...)
    : wxFrame(...)
{
    wxPanel* p = new wxPanel(this);
    p->Bind(wxEVT_MOTION, &MyFrame::OnMouseMotion, this);
}
```

would allow you to handle mouse motion events happening over the panel in a frame method.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly true.

Some mouse events go to the frame, like wxEVT_ENTER (or whatever it is called). Others go to the panel, e.g. wxEVT_RIGHT_UP. You can forward those events to the frame.

Bind to the event in both the panel and the frame.

```
Bind(wxEVT_RIGHT_UP, &MyFrame::OnMouse, ptr_to_myframe);
Bind(wxEVT_RIGHT_UP, &MyPanel::OnMouse, ptr_to_panel);
```

And then (assuming the frame is the parent of the panel),

```
void MyPanel::OnMouse(wxMouseEvent &event) {
    wxPostEvent(GetParent(), event);
}
```

If the panel is scrolled, you probably want to forward an event with the unscrolled coordinates.

```
void MyScrolledPanel::OnMouse(wxMouseEvent &event) {
    wxMouseEvent pevent(event);
    CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetX(), event.GetY(), &pevent.m_x, &pevent.m_y);
    wxPostEvent(GetParent(), pevent); 
}
```