# Have a wx Python widget react on mouse clicks from the entire window (globally)?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

With the code snippet below, which produces something like this:

[image: test.png]

... I want to have the blue (subclassed Panel) widget turn red, every time the user left clicks with the mouse *anywhere* in the application frame window. As it is currently, it reacts only when the widget itself is clicked - but it doesn't react to, say, clicks on the button or elsewhere in the frame.

So my question is:

- Is this widget-listening-to-"global"-clicks possible at all in wxPython?
- If it is - how do I do it in the example below?

(Just changing the parent, e.g. `self.parent.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS, self.OnMouseEvents)` does not work at all; I also found [wx.lib.evtmgr](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.evtmgr-module.html), but I simply cannot find the right syntax to set it up so it works).

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.3 on Mon Jan 12 21:20:22 2015

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0, name="MyPanel"):
    super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent, id, pos, size, style, name)
    self.parent = parent
    self.lmb = False
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS, self.OnMouseEvents) # only reacts on its own clicks, not globally!
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
  def OnMouseEvents(self, event):
    print("OnMouseEvents")
    self.lmb = event.LeftDown() or event.LeftIsDown()
    self.Refresh(False)
  def OnPaint(self, event):
    w, h = self.GetSize()
    if self.lmb: mybrush = wx.Brush(wx.NamedColour("red"))
    else: mybrush = wx.Brush(wx.NamedColour("blue"))
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
    dc.SetBrush(mybrush)
    dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "button_1")
        self.panel_1 = MyPanel(self, -1)

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")
        self.SetSize((200, 200))
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, 0, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I know PyQt better, but when you bind on click on the panel, then it is only in for the panel itself. I don't know if that's possible, to lay it on the whole window (so the button would be overlayed by the whole window layer)

Comment: Thanks for that, @ProgrammingIsAwsome - wasn't aware of that, am just finding links like [wxWidgets Discussion Forum • View topic - Problem with mouse events](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=26197) which mention precisely that... Cheers!

Comment: So I'm not sure I'm just guessing because for me this overlay would not produce good results. I mean then the button there would be overlayed or do multiple things at a time

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got this to work; note however that:

- "wxMouseEvent does NOT propagate" [wxWidgets Discussion Forum • View topic - Problem with mouse events](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=26197)
- "Various sources say it is not possible (to catch mouse events in the actual wxFrame element) and wxPanels should be used to capture events" ; "Some mouse events go to the frame, like wxEVT_ENTER (or whatever it is called). Others go to the panel, e.g. wxEVT_RIGHT_UP. You can forward those events to the frame." ; "Mouse events are not propagated upwards the window hierarchy, so if your frame is entirely covered by other windows, then it doesn't get any mouse events in the first place and hence you can't catch them there." [Is it possible to catch mouse events in wxFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616599/is-it-possible-to-catch-mouse-events-in-wxframe)
- "whenever you have one child of a wxFrame, wxWidgets automatically assumes you want it to cover the entire area of the wxFrame. Because of this, there is no portion of the frame visible - hence none of the events make it to your handler." [Not catching all mouse events with wxWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510313/not-catching-all-mouse-events-with-wxwidgets/2510486#2510486)

All this considered, the solution is to:

- recursively walk through all of the (child) widgets in the frame;
- connect individually  their mouse left down/up events to a single event handler;
- Make sure that single event handler ends with `event.Skip()` so the event is propagated to the original button etc, so its original click handlers work too.

With that, now with the code below I get this:

[image: test.png]

Note that the area where the mouse is on the screenshot is "covered" by a sizer, but sizers do not handle clicks - so basically it is the frame itself that responds to the click there (turning the monitoring square red). So basically each widget on the surface of the frame window handles its own area; and whatever is not covered - even if there are sizers present in that area - is actually handled by the frame.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# generated by wxGlade 0.6.3 on Mon Jan 12 21:20:22 2015

import wx

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0, name="MyPanel"):
    super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent, id, pos, size, style, name)
    self.lmb = False
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS, self.OnMouseEvents) # only reacts on its own clicks, not globally! # use RecursiveSetListeners now; should be called from parent class after all init layout is done
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
  def OnMouseEvents(self, event):
    print("OnMouseEvents")
    self.lmb = event.LeftDown() or event.LeftIsDown()
    self.Refresh(False)
    event.Skip() # propagate, in case button is clicked
  def OnPaint(self, event):
    w, h = self.GetSize()
    if self.lmb: mybrush = wx.Brush(wx.NamedColour("red"))
    else: mybrush = wx.Brush(wx.NamedColour("blue"))
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
    dc.SetBrush(mybrush)
    dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h)
  def RecursiveSetListeners(self, inwidget):
    print("setting listeners: " + inwidget.GetName())
    inwidget.Connect(wx.ID_ANY, -1, wx.wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseEvents)
    inwidget.Connect(wx.ID_ANY, -1, wx.wxEVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseEvents)
    for child in inwidget.GetChildren():
      self.RecursiveSetListeners(child)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__init__
    kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
    self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "button_1", name="button_1")
    self.panel_1 = MyPanel(self, -1, name="panel_1")
    self.button_2 = wx.Button(self.panel_1, -1, "button_2", name="button_1")
    #self.Connect(wx.ID_ANY, -1, wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS, self.panel_1.OnMouseEvents) # 'wx.wxEVT_MOUSE_EVENTS: AttributeError: 'module' has no attribute 'wxEVT_MOUSE_EVENTS';; wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS: TypeError: in method 'EvtHandler_Connect', expected argument 4 of type 'int'
    # these work:
    #self.Connect(wx.ID_ANY, -1, wx.wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.panel_1.OnMouseEvents)
    #self.Connect(wx.ID_ANY, -1, wx.wxEVT_LEFT_UP, self.panel_1.OnMouseEvents)
    #self.button_1.Connect(wx.ID_ANY, -1, wx.wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.panel_1.OnMouseEvents)
    #self.button_1.Connect(wx.ID_ANY, -1, wx.wxEVT_LEFT_UP, self.panel_1.OnMouseEvents)

    self.__set_properties()
    self.__do_layout()
    print(self.GetChildren())
    self.panel_1.RecursiveSetListeners(self)
    # end wxGlade

  def __set_properties(self):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__set_properties
    self.SetTitle("frame_1")
    self.SetSize((200, 200))
    # end wxGlade

  def __do_layout(self):
    # begin wxGlade: MyFrame.__do_layout
    sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_2.Add(self.button_2, 0,0,0)
    self.panel_1.SetSizer(sizer_2)
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, 0, 0)
    sizer_1.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.Layout()
    # end wxGlade

# end of class MyFrame

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
  wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
  frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
  app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
  frame_1.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```